# Javascript change value object in function from chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have this code extract taken from an imported javascript page with the  tag inside an html page:

```
2: [function(e, t) {
    "use strict";
    amo.timer = {
        CONTO: 10,
        LOST: 4,
        COVER_DATA: 140,
        STAMP_MODE: 20,
        LOOP: {
            ALT_1: 60,
            ALT_2: 14
        },
        COMBINANCE: {
            mode_1: 40,
            mode_2: 12,
            mode_3: 15,
          restpost: 0.5,
            status_log: 0.5
        },
        REGISTER_AMP: {
            mode_1: 20,
            mode_2: 11,
            mode_3: 0.5,

        },

    }
}, {}],
```

I wanted to ask if I could change the value of ALT_1 with the chome console and how.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That function only sets the global object `amo.timer`, so you can do the same:

```
amo.timer.LOOP.ALT_1 = 61;
```

Alternatively, you have to replace the complete function with a function that sets the values you want.